# How do I re-write my VueJS2 components using VueJS3 syntax?

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs3

I have upgraded my Laravel 5.8 to Laravel 9 and now I am using `ViteJS` instead of `laravel-mix`.
My Vue components now looks there are obsolete some how:

```
Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. Install @vitejs/plugin-vue to handle .vue files.
19:24:27 [vite] Internal server error: Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. Install @vitejs/plugin-vue to handle .vue files.
  Plugin: vite:import-analysis
  File: /Users/marcellopato/Documents/Sites/wb9/resources/js/components/UploadForm.vue:6:101
  4  |              <input type="file" name="image" class="" @change="GetImage" accept="image/*">
  5  |              <img :src="avatar" alt="Imagem" class="drop">
  6  |              <a href="#" v-if="loaded" class="btn btn-success m-t-10" @click.stop="Upload">Enviar</a>
     |                                                                                                      ^
  7  |              <a href="#" v-if="loaded" class="btn btn-danger m-t-10" @click.stop="Cancel">Cancelar</a>
  8  |              <span class="custom-file-control text-muted"><slot></slot> CPF: <span v-text="cpf"></span></span>
      at formatError (file:///Users/marcellopato/Documents/Sites/wb9/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5e7f419b.js:41235:46)
      at TransformContext.error (file:///Users/marcellopato/Documents/Sites/wb9/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5e7f419b.js:41231:19)
      at TransformContext.transform (file:///Users/marcellopato/Documents/Sites/wb9/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5e7f419b.js:39475:22)
      at async Object.transform (file:///Users/marcellopato/Documents/Sites/wb9/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5e7f419b.js:41506:30)
      at async loadAndTransform (file:///Users/marcellopato/Documents/Sites/wb9/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5e7f419b.js:39313:29)
```

I did install the `@vitejs/plugin-vue` plugin and imported on `app.js` file like so:

`import '@vitejs/plugin-vue';` but looks like it is not working. Should it re-wirte my .vue files?
Or maybe I should re-write by myself? There is a guide to follow?

Comment: If it is not **needed**, don't rewrite them. No point in breaking your app and redoing it from top to bottom if it already works. Update only where it's needed/blocking and mainly: do it incrementally when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your `package.json` and your `vite.config.js` files like below

**package.json** :

```json
"@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.2.0",
"vite": "^3.0.0",
```

**vite.config.js** :

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: But something is not right. Looks like my blade file is not using the correct syntax. Can you tell me where can I find, how can I upgrade it? Thanks!